# Dictionary with high low pitch intonation reading?

Tags: dictionary

Forgive me if there is a more appropriate technical term for the thing I'm searching for. When I studied Japanese in Taiwan a few years back, I learned that it was important to learn the right high low pitch intonation for new words. This was usually noted by a number between 0 and 6 (I think), as in おはよう０ or 犬（いぬ２）. The Japanese/Chinese hardbound dictionary I still have from then has these numbers for all entries, but now that I'm trying to get back into Japanese study, but with my cell phone and computer, I can't find an online dictionary or app (android preferably) that has them. I looked through all the suggestions on the resources page here, but none of them seems to have them. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: http://accent.u-biq.org/english.html maybe?

Comment: Yes! This is just what I'm asking about. Am I right in assuming that this is not a much paid attention to aspect of pronunciation for beginners like myself, seeing as how it's not a part of most dictionary entries?

Comment: I've gone ahead and added an answer to our meta post on resources: [**Resources for pitch accent**](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese/1496#1496) ← Please, everyone, feel free to add resources or work on the descriptions I've written :-)

Comment: [NHK日本語発音アクセント辞典(無料)](https://sakura-paris.org/dict/NHK%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E7%99%BA%E9%9F%B3%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E8%BE%9E%E5%85%B8/)